# Navigation bar doesn't render properly in IE 10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, flexbox

I'm having some issues with IE 10. [Code here.](http://goo.gl/CXVEjg)
On latest Chrome and Firefox all the text is rendered in one line. But in IE it renders like this [image: Rendering issues on IE 10]   meanwhile any other modern browser produces [image: Rendering issues on IE 10].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.gh-nav-panel {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;  /*this will vertically align your text to the middle*/
}
```

Comment: Nah. It's caused by something else.

Comment: When i viewed your js.fiddle in IE the text alignment was off and I was using IE11. The vertical-align:middle; worked. As another suggestion you might want to try adding * {padding:0; margin:0;} to your CSS. UL and LI tags added margin/padding dependent on browser type.

Comment: I'd like gh-tab-link with "Test" to take 100% of gh-nav-panel-home. It's only possible when it has display set to block and this causes this weird behaviour.

Comment: A couple of updates to your code and I removed that <SPAN> did you have to have that? http://jsfiddle.net/ycox9xmj/7/